# Map a url directory to localhost

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, hosts

Is it possible to "spoof" / map a specific url so that when it is requested, it actually requests a diferent URL (e.g. 127.0.0.1:8008/abc) ?

This is the structure of the environment:
`http://int.company.com/site/subsite`

I want all requests (by my local development machine) to map
`http://int.company.com/site/localspoof`
to
`http://127.0.0.1:8008/localspoof`

Is this at all possible? All requests to `http://int.company.com/site/subsite` would resolve normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

In the AutoResponder tab, tick "Enabled automatic responses" and "Unmatched requests passthrough"

Add a rule...

Match:

`regex:(?i)http://int.company.com/site/localspoof/(.*)`

Respond with:

`http://127.0.0.1:8008/localspoof/$1`

This will capture all traffic under subfolder on a site, and transparently map a local server / folder to any resources specified in the URI.